# Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [5] rhs shape= [1001]

Tags: python-3.x

When I run the code in https://github.com/caicloud/tensorflow-tutorial/blob/master/Deep_Learning_with_TensorFlow/1.4.0/Chapter06/2.2%20fine_tuning.ipynb

I got the error：

`InvalidArgumentError` (see above for traceback): 
Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [5] rhs shape= [1001]

[[Node: save/Assign_8 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2b_1x1/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2b_1x1/biases, save/RestoreV2_8)]]

The var trainable_variables in this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkRf5.png) does not used ?

How to fix it?

main code for transfer learning:

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, CHANNELS], name='input_images')
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None], name='labels')

#define the model
with slim.arg_scope(inception_v3.inception_v3_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = inception_v3.inception_v3(images, num_classes=N_CLASSES, is_training=True)

# get the trainables_var with the function get_trainable_variables()
trainable_variables = get_trainable_variables()
tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(tf.one_hot(labels, N_CLASSES), logits, weights=1.0)
train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(tf.losses.get_total_loss())

with tf.name_scope('evaluation'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), labels)
    evaluation_step = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


load_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
                    CKPT_FILE,
                    get_tuned_variables(), ignore_missing_vars = True)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    print('Loading tuned_variables from %s'%CKPT_FILE)
    load_fn(sess)
```

Comment: please include the important piece of code you have linked in your post.